# make mbsync+IMAP behave like POP

Tags: imap, davmail

My work insists on Outlook365 and I use it in the most minimal way possible.  That is, I pull email to my local machine à la POP and manage it there.  Because of recent migration to MFA I have had to change my setup to davmail+IMAP+mbsync.  All (eventually!) is now working satisfactorily except I would like my emails to be deleted on the Outlook365 server once successfully downloaded.

What options should I specify in my `~/.mbsyncrc` file to achieve auto-deletion?  Currently I have these options set but they aren't working.

```
Channel work
Master :work-store:
Slave :local:
Patterns INBOX
Expunge Master
Sync Pull New Delete
SyncState *
```

Many thanks.